# Event handling on the worker thread

Tags: android, multithreading, event-handling

I need to capture data from the accelerometer and I need fast changes, so I use SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST.
The problem is that it creates hundreds (maybe thousands) of events per sec and its making my UI thread very slow.

Is there a way to capture accelerometer events on a worker thread (I tried on a IntentService, only to find out that android Services run by default on the UI thread)

**EDIT**

I don't do a lot of processing for the event, basically I just put it in a queue that holds the last 200 events.

Comment: create a new thread and run the same. i guess you can use a executor.

Comment: Nope.  Your best bet is to change your rate.  Note that on 2.3+, you can specify rate in ms rather than normal, fast, etc.  That may help.  The other thing you can do is offload more work from the UI thread in other calls.

Comment: @Raghunandan-  that won't help much, unless he's doing a lot of processing on the sensor events that can be offloaded to another thread-  the sensor event comes on a callback from the OS, it will always come on the UI thread.  Even then it won't actually speed things up unless the Linux scheduler actually passes the other thread to another core, which due to memory locality it probably would try to avoid.

Comment: edited question, basically I don't do much processing. So the only thing I can do is lower the event rate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Acclerometer Sensor in Separate Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513352/acclerometer-sensor-in-separate-thread)